# Purpose of spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor?

Tags: spring-boot

What is the purpose of:

```
annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor"
```

My application is working fine with or without it. The thin jar that I create, is also working fine in dependent project.

I am asking this because that line is working fine when I include it in local build.gradle. But as soon I push it to cloud, I get this error:

> > Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

So I was thinking to do without it. I am not seeing any affect on the thin jar  or the dependent project.

Also, [This page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-custom-starter-module-autoconfigure) says that I must use annotationProcessor in build.gradle when using Gradle 4.6 or above. What if I use compileOnly option in Gradle 4.8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor` is an annotation processor that generates the file `META-INF/spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties` for inclusion in your project's jar. This file helps with startup time, but is not necessary for your app to function correctly.

From [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-custom-starter-module-autoconfigure):

> If that file is present, it is used to eagerly filter
>   auto-configurations that do not match, which will improve startup
>   time.

Comment: Hi @Chris. Do you know if this dependency could help with the following error. It started to happen after upgradin to spring boot 2.7 (with Scala/Sbt)  " No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories nor in META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct."

Comment: @dhalfageme no, that won't help you. Either use the spring-boot-maven-plugin which will generate spring.factories file for you, or create it yourself like [mentioned here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration#creating-a-custom-auto-configuration).

Comment: I tried to add it bit It seems is not found. Please can you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73897227/sbt-spring-boot-no-auto-configuration-classes-found-in-meta-inf-spring-factori) where I specified several plugins I tried?. Spring boot maven plugin was tried but couldnt be resolved (maybe It is only for maven but no sbt?) I also tried to change merge strategy for assembly to reflect the nee default path of the sprint.factories with no luck. Thanks in  advance