# Sbt + Spring boot No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring-boot, scala, sbt

after upgrading from Spring boot 2.4.13 to 2.7.4 I started facing this error on my containerized Scala application (I am using scala 2.12)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories nor in META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:470)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:185)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationEntry(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:440)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.eb.data.batch.writer.TermSuccessBatchMainClass$.main(TermSuccessBatch.scala:61)
    at com.eb.data.batch.writer.TermSuccessBatchMainClass.main(TermSuccessBatch.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

After making some research, I found possible solutions like including one of these plugins on `plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.9.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.9.11")
addSbtPlugin("org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-maven-plugin" % "2.7.4")
```

However, I am not able to resolve the last 2 of these plugins, but the file contains other plugins that are properly resolved si I discarded a repository configuration problem. Indeed, the first one can be resolved but didn't fix the issue. I also appended this line to `build.sbt`:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

```
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:1.9.11
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.12_1.0/1.9.11/sbt-native-packager-1.9.11.pom
[error]   not found: /Users/myuser/.ivy2/localcom.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.9.11/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   unauthorized: https://my-nexus-server/repository/ivy-releases-group/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.9.11/ivys/artifact.xml (Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager)
[error]   unauthorized: https://my-nexus-server/repository/public/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.12_1.0/1.9.11/sbt-native-packager-1.9.11.pom (Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager)
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.9.11/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.9.11/ivys/ivy.xml
```

The last two are throwing an unauthorized error on my nexus repository but .sbt credentials are properly set and it is able to resolve any dependencies an other plugins through the nexus server (I guess it is a Not found instead).

Also tried to modify the merge strategy from

```
lazy val assemblySettings = Seq(
  assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
    case PathList("META-INF", "spring.factories") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case _                             => MergeStrategy.first
  }
)
```

to

```
lazy val assemblySettings = Seq(
  assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
    case PathList("META-INF", "spring.factories") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
    case PathList("META-INF", "spring") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case _                             => MergeStrategy.first
  }
)
```

since the autoconfiguration seems to have been moved on spring boot 2.7 and the error message says it is tried to locate it also under `META-INF/spring` It didn't work

Any ideas to face this issue?

Comment: Spring Boot does not support Scala. There was an attempt few years ago but it was abandoned. If I were you, I’d not try to fit a square peg in a round hole. Use a framework that natively supports Scala, like Play or Akka.

Comment: We have been using spring boot on the project since years ago. We only use It to inject config properties/env variables into beans and loading some configs beans based on profiles. It has worked OK until this upgrade and fits very well with our purposes

Comment: I mean, we do not use It to create a service but only for configuration purposes on a spark batch application

Comment: All I can say is that Scala isn’t supported by Spring. If you want to continue spending time on unsupported software just because you’ve gotten lucky so far, that’s up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the spring auto configuration settings have been moved on spring 2.7 from `META-INF/spring.factories` to `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`,
replacing this path on the merge strategy for sbt build worked:

```
  assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
    case PathList("META-INF", "spring.factories") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines // Not sure if something in this path is needed anymore
    case PathList("META-INF", "spring", "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case _                             => MergeStrategy.first
  }
```