# spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor vs spring-boot-configuration-processor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I see two types of dependencies can be included for a spring boot application.

`<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor</artifactId> </dependency>`

`<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId> </dependency>`

are these 2 different dependencies, what is the difference? when to use autoconfigure-processor and when to use configuration-processor?

I did a bit of search and gathered the below notes per the answers in soo. i understood both dependencies are doing the same effect.

[Purpose of spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266569/purpose-of-spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor)

spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor - is an annotation processor that generates the file META-INF/spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties for inclusion in your project's jar. This file helps with startup time but is unnecessary for your app to function correctly.

Link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration.custom-starter.autoconfigure-module

[What is the spring-boot-configuration-processor ? Why do people exclude libraries from it? Why is it invisible in dependency tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707080/what-is-the-spring-boot-configuration-processor-why-do-people-exclude-librarie)

spring-boot-configuration-processor - is an annotation processor that generates metadata about classes in your application that are annotated with @ConfigurationProperties. This metadata is used by your IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, or NetBeans) to provide auto-completion and documentation for the properties when editing application.properties and application.yaml files. You can learn more about it in the relevant section of Spring Boot's reference documentation.

Link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.configuration-metadata.annotation-processor